# laravel 5: relationship between products and featured products

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, table-relationships

I'm writing a sample ecommerce website with Laravel 5.
I have 2 Tables:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->float('price');
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and

```
Schema::create('featureds', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('product_id')->unique()->unsigned();
});

Schema::table('featureds', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Models**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }    
}

class Featured extends Model
{
    public function product(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Then, I have a `Controller`, where I take 4 `featured products`:

```
$featured_products = Featured::limit(4)->get();
return view('home', ['featured_products' => $featured_products]);
```

Now, I'm trying to show these featured products in my view. If i show the `product_id` from the `Featured model`, everything is ok:

```
@foreach($featured_products as $prod)
  {{$prod->product_id}}
@endforeach
```

But I want to take the name of the `product` referred by the featured. I tried this way:

```
@foreach($featured_products as $prod)
  @foreach($prod as $p)
    {{$p->name}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Because `featured_products` (in the `controller`) seems to be a collection, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Featured` model, you have a relationship in method `product()` when you want to access the relation from the view, you could call the method name as property, in you case, you have a method named `product()` so you have to call `product` property like this:

```
@foreach($featured_products as $prod)
    {{ $prod->product->name }}
@endforeach
```

It will automatically write the `product name` based on the relationship you have configured in the model.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Edit:

Sorry my bad, I guess you are defining a wrong relation, your `Product` model, should have a `featured()` method which uses `hasOne` relation, while `Featured` model should have a `product()` method using `belongsTo` relation. So in you `App\Featured` model, you have to define the relation like this:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
```

And in your `App\Product` model you should define relation like so:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Featured');
```

Hope it works

Comment: Hi, first thank you for the help.
I tried this way, but it returns this:
`ErrorException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'products' where 'products'.'product_id' is null and 'products'.'product_id' is not null limit 1) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/projects/mwt-lamp/resources/views/widgets/featured.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/projects/mwt-lamp/resources/views/widgets/featured.blade.php)`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I guess you are defining a wrong relation, your `Product` model, should have a `featured()` method which uses `hasOne` relation, while `Featured` model should have a `product()` method using `belongsTo` relation. So in you `App\Featured` model, you have to define the relation like this `return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');`. And in your `App\Product` model you should define relation like so `return $this->hasOne('App\Featured');`. Hope it works

Comment: Yeah, it works, i just changed `hasOne` to `belongsTo` on function `product()` into `Featured` model.
Can you edit the answer, so i can set it as Answer?
Thank you

Comment: okay, I have edited my answer, thank you and glad it works! Cheers!